# android GLSurfaceView draw out of parent's bounds when scaled

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView in a FrameLayout, when I scale the FrameLayout,the GLSurfaceView draw out of it's parents bounds. [click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpPyQ.png) How can I fix this issue?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```